# PHP show the most popular tags

Tags: php, mysql, function, tags

I have a database like this:

```
+----+---------------------+
| id | tags                |
+----+---------------------+
| 1  | test1, test2, test3 |
| 2  | test1, test2, test3 |
| 3  | test1, test2, test3 |
| 4  | test1, test2, test3 |
| 5  | buh1, buh2, buh3    |
+----+---------------------+
```

Now i want to display the most popular tags from this database. I have a function, and it works with a array like this:

> $tag_array = array(
>       'test1, test2 test, test3',
>       'test2, test4, test2',
>       'buh, buh2, buh3' );

The function:

```
function popularTags($tag_array) {
    $p = array();
    foreach($tag_array as $tags) {
        $tags_arr = array_map('trim', explode(',', $tags));
        foreach($tags_arr as $tag) {
            $p[$tag] = array_key_exists($tag, $p) ? $p[$tag]+1 : 1;
        }
    }
    arsort($p);
    return $p;
}
```

This is how to display the most popular tags:

```
foreach(popularTags($tag_array) as $tag=>$num)
{
    echo $tag, " (", $num, ")<br />";
}
```

This works so far, with a normal array.

Now, i want to get the tags from the Database, so i extract the values from the database and run the function like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from DB ORDER BY date DESC");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

   $tag_array = $row["$tags"];

foreach(popularTags($tag_array) as $tag=>$num)
{
    echo $tag, " (", $num, ")<br />";
}

}
```

This give me an error though:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

So my question is how to show the most popular tags from the database with this function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one works for me:

```
$result = mysql_query("select tags from DATABASE LIMIT 20");

$tags = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $row_tag_array = split(",", $row[0]);
    foreach ($row_tag_array as $newtag) {
    asort($row_tag_array);
        if (array_key_exists($newtag, $tags)) {
            if ($tags[$newtag] < 200) {
                $tags[$newtag] = $tags[$newtag] + 20;

            }
        }
        else {
            $tags[$newtag] = 100;
        }
    }
}

foreach ($tags as $tag => $size) {
    echo "<a style=\"font-size: $size%;\" href=\"?t=$tag\">$tag</a> ";

}
```

Thank you for your help though

Answer (score 8):

My suggestion is that you [normalize](http://www.keithjbrown.co.uk/vworks/mysql/mysql_p7.php) your database. Then a query like this becomes trivial, as well as much better performing.

```
select TagID, count(*)
from EntityTag
group by TagID
order by count(*) descending
limit 5
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_array returns all the rows.  So do this:

```
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($result);
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $tag_array = $row["tags"]; // note removing the $
    foreach(...) {
    }
}
```

Comment: It somehow work, but it does not display any tags, instead it display something like this:

`(1)
(2)
(3)
(4)
(5)
(6)
(7)
(8)
(9)
(10)`

Comment: sorry I am replying hastily.  I will figure this out in a minute.

Comment: Thank you, your new reply gives error :-)
`Warning: preg_split() [function.preg-split]: No ending delimiter ',' found in`

Comment: I still cant it to work, i try like this:
`$rows = mysql_fetch_array($result);
   
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $tag_array = $row["tags"]; // note removing the $
   
foreach(popularTags($tag_array) as $tag=>$num)
{
    echo $tag, " (", $num, ")<br />";
}

}`

Comment: It gives me this error:
`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: do $x = popularTags($tag_array); print_r($x); exit;  and see if you are getting the expected result;

Comment: If i make a while and extract the row and then make an array like this `$tag_array = array($tags);` it work kind of, but in a lot of seperate arrays instead of one